# How can I make the rendered image to look like what the character looks like in object mode?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I basically want the rendered image to look like what the character looks like in object mode. How can I achieve this? Also one of my characters eyes is white while the other is solid, and his hair wont render. Here are some pictures to show what I'm talking about.

[image]

[image: https://imgur.com/a/9wNclZz]

[File](http://drive.google.com/open?id=1CBL0wX5ptRBfoR7ZCXoBOfqAblD1Y3d_)

Comment: Why not simply capture the OpenGL render from thew viewport?

Comment: HI, if you can, share your file through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then edit your post and paste the provided link

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hey bro if this is what you are looking for the solution is simple

1. navigate to the outliner tab
   [image]
2. Make sure that every object in the scene is enabled for render (make sure that the camera icon beside every object is not grey in color )

[image]

I hope this solves your problem. :)

Comment: Hey that looks great I will do that now, thanks!